# How can I pass the isConnect state to the other class

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Now I have `App.js` is my init page.
I want listen internet status from `net_provide.js`. 
If `isConnected` is true then `APP.js` show `renderLoadingView()`
If not then `APP.js` show `renderDisconnectView()` like below code
But I don't know how to pass the isConnected from `net_provide.js` to `APP.js`
Can anyone help me? Thank you!

App.js

```
renderLoadingView() {
    _aesDecryptWithMode(_aesEncryptWithMode('test'))
    getFcmToken()
    return (
      <View style={ styles.container }>
        <NetworkNotifier
          offlineText="無網路連線"
          onlineText="網路已連線"
          position="top" />
        <Network_provider/>
        <Text>
          Loading Events....
          { '\n' }
        </Text>
      </View>
    )
  }

  renderDisconnectView() {
    return (
      <View style={ styles.container }>
        <Network_provider/>
        <Text>
          diss
          { '\n' }
        </Text>
      </View>
    )

  }
```

The problem is here
this.props.Connected

```
  render() {
    return (
   if (this.props.isConnected) {
     return this.renderLoadingView();
   }
   if (!this.props.isConnected) {
     return this.renderDisconnectView();
   }

  }
```

And below is network_provider.js

```
export class Network_provider extends React.PureComponent {
  state = {
    isConnected: true
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    NetInfo.isConnected.addEventListener('connectionChange', this.handleConnectivityChange);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    NetInfo.isConnected.removeEventListener('connectionChange', this.handleConnectivityChange);
  }

  handleConnectivityChange = isConnected => {
    if (isConnected) {
      this.setState({
        isConnected
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        isConnected
      });
    }
  };

  render() {
    return <App Connected={ this.state.isConnected } />;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `this.props.isConnected` to `this.props.Connected`, since you are passing a prop called Connected to App component in Network_provider

```
 render() {
   return (
       if (this.props.Connected) {
         return this.renderLoadingView();
       }
       if (!this.props.Connected) {
         return this.renderDisconnectView();
       }
     );
  }
```

what is the value passed to `handleConnectivityChange` if its a Boolean then you can shorten it like this.

```
  handleConnectivityChange = isConnected => {
    this.setState({
        isConnected:isConnected
      });
  };
```

**Update** 
Try this in you child component. first set an initial state and use componentDidUpdate to check is props changed. like this

```
this.state={
 Connected:true //default value
}

componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (this.props.Connected!== prevProps.Connected) {
      this.setState({Connected:this.props.Connected})
    }
  }

 render() {
    return (
        if (this.state.Connected) {
           return this.renderLoadingView();
         }
        if (!this.state.Connected) {
           return this.renderDisconnectView();
         }
      );
 }
```

Comment: I would say change `Connected` to `isConnected` in `<App Connected={ this.state.isConnected } />`

Comment: @wanjas well that is the same thing :D

Comment: Actually,I just paste it error.
The status still no change when I ON/OFF my internet connection

Comment: Thank you for your respond~But still not worked:( So I give up it~
now I use context to handle the isConnected state but I have another problem maybe i will post it!

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Function as Children** pattern for that.

network_provider.js

```
render() {
  const { children } = this.props;
  const { isConnected } = this.state;

  return children && children({isConnected});
}
```

App.js

```
<Network_provider>
  {({isConnected}) => {
    if(isConnected) return this.renderDisconnectView();
    return this.renderLoadingView();
    }
  }
</Network_provider>
```